# Python 2.7 or Python 3 (for speed)?

Tags: python

I've looked around for answers and much seems to be old or outdated. Has Python 3 been updated yet so that it's decently faster than Python 2.7 or am I still better off sticking with my workable code?

Comment: Unicode support for certain use case is better in Python 3.

Comment: Python 3 has some new optimizations in part of the language, but Python2 has the [`pypy` JIT VM](http://www.pypy.org) which can get you major speed improvements. What's your question though? If you already have python 2 compatible code, you can either stay with Python 2, or move to Python 3 with some code changes (unless there are libs you can't get in Python 3).

Comment: @birryree My question is if I could expect speed improvements by porting over to Python 3. I couldn't get pypy working on Windows.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The issue isn't about speed -- they're either the same speed or Python 3.x is faster (depending on which benchmarks you look at). More specifically, Python 2 used to be faster, but apparently, they're on par with each other now (?). See the comments and this [slide deck](https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/python-3-dot-3-trust-me-its-better-than-python-2-dot-7-by-dr-brett-cannon) (towards the back).

The core devs are also actively working on optimizing Python 3 -- each new release of Python 3 has been [faster than the last](http://igordavydenko.com/talks/by-pycon-2017/). You can keep abreast of the latest proposals and ideas on optimizing Python (as well as the many complications) by monitoring the [python-dev mailing list](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-dev).

Rather, the reason many people used to give for not updated is because when Python 3 came out, and for several years after, the majority of Python libraries were not updated to work on Python 3.x. However, thankfully, this situation is vastly improved today -- the majority of 3rd party libraries are now Python 3 compatible.

The [Python FAQ](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) contains more info. You can also check the [Python Wall of Superpowers](https://python3wos.appspot.com/) or [Py3 Readiness](http://py3readiness.org/) to get an overview of which popular Python libraries are currently compatible with Python 3.

**Update: (Summer 2017)**

I feel somewhat obligated to note that support for Python 2 is [formally ending in 2020](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/).

Many 3rd party libraries are also planning on following suit -- a large subset of the scientific ecosystem (e.g. matplotlib, pandas, ipython) are planning on [dropping support for Python 2 in 2020](http://www.python3statement.org/), Django is [dropping support](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2015/jun/25/roadmap/)... I wouldn't be surprised if other libraries do the same.

So, if you're interested in making sure you can use the latest and greatest features in either Python or your favorite library, you should look into migrating to Python 3 sooner rather than later.

Here are some guides on converting Python 2 to 3 code:

- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html
- http://python3porting.com/
- https://eev.ee/blog/2016/07/31/python-faq-how-do-i-port-to-python-3/

Comment: This is also precisely (the other reason) why I haven't updated yet. It seems like support is limited for many of the libraries I use.

Comment: Actually, Python 3 tends to be slightly slower than 2.x. Not by much and you can treat them as the same for practical purposes, but the fact that every integer is now a `long` and every string is now `unicode` does have some overhead.

Comment: There are other major speed improvements though in particular in threading and GIL, so if you are going to use it for something that involves threads (most webservers) or some intensive computations probably >=3.2 will be faster overall.

Comment: My PyQt/numpy app is around 10% slower running its self tests on Python 3.3.2 compared to 2.7.5. This is using x86-64 linux with a single compatible codebase.

Comment: @kindall: Python 3.3 is now on par with 2.7. See [Brett Cannon's slides](https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/python-3-dot-3-trust-me-its-better-than-python-2-dot-7-by-dr-brett-cannon).

Comment: @NagabhushanBaddi -- if you have a specific issue with the benchmarks listed in the linked slides, or can point to an alternate set of benchmarks/data to back up your claim, please do so. (As a piece of advice, simply asserting a claim doesn't really gain you any credibility, especially in tech circles. You should get into the habit of always backing up your claims with data immediately and up front. If your data is strong, it should speak for itself.)

Comment: @NagabhushanBaddi yes, please do provide proof.

Comment: On my test program (of all permutations of a given word, find matching words in Linux American English dictionary), the RAM usage bloats by 20%. Which is significant enough to reduce the maximum letters that I can use without hitting swap memory and exploding the computation time. So it's certainly not a "non-issue". But for most people it's probably an acceptable loss.

Comment: So you (the question answerer) feels obliged to post promotional material to a question that only asked about speed, which you tried to not answer because you think the answer might lead people to not use your promoted product.

And then other people who have a vested interest or who try to promote one product over the other close the question as being "not constructive" because it interferes with their promotional goals too.

Comment: This might be anecdotal, but I was once iterating through a tokenized list of a ~150MB corpus and looking up these words in a dict. Python 2.7 took DAYS where Python 3 took <1 hour. I assume it's a bug in that release, or is somehow not optimized for my hardware, surely I'm not supposed to see orders of magnitude speed improvements.

Comment: It's interesting this question is closed because I'm using Python `2.7.12` in Ubuntu 16.04 and may continue to do so for a few years. Soon it will by Python `4` in the current Ubuntu 20.04 or 21.04 or whatever. As my project grows closer to 20,000 lines I'm naturally curious if it will be slower or faster in python 3.x or 4.x or 5.x or whatever is current when I finally bite the bullet and upgrade Python.

Answer (score 14):

FYI, [here](https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/python-3-dot-3-trust-me-its-better-than-python-2-dot-7-by-dr-brett-cannon)'s a performance benchmark comparing Python 2.7 with Python 3.3. Python 3.3 comes faster than Python 2.7.

Comment: @JimFerrans ok, it's updated now

Answer (score 9):

Python 3.3 included an optimization for Unicode strings that reduced their memory consumption. That *might* translate into faster code if more of it fits into cache.

Really the only way to know is to benchmark your most critical code in both and see what the difference is.

Comment: I agree -- benchmarking is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

The necessity of Libraries for your applications will determine whether Python3 or Pyhton2 is better.

Comment: He asked about speed, not which is better. He asked for information, not a judgement or preference.